# Executing VB6 exe in non-VB environment

Tags: vb6, exe

I have created a Vb application/exe using `ADODC` components and common dialog box. but I am not able to run that application on another PC where VB6 is not installed.

Do I have to install some additional components on that PC? (Don't want to install VB6 there).

How can I configure `ODBC` connection using code which we do manually from Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources -> Add new -> mdb ?

Comment: Did you install the vb runtime requirements on the desitation pc?

Comment: Yes I installed vb6 runtime environment on that PC. (which is approx 1MB) but still its not working.

Comment: What errors etc do you get? Normally things like setting the odbc will be done through the installer..

Comment: component 'COMDLG32.OCX' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered:a file is missing or invalid

Comment: I even tried to install comdlg32 on my pc but it didnt worked too.

Comment: Then you need to package that in the installer too

Comment: Even after installing and registering comdlg32.ocx I am getting the same error

Comment: You need to check all the dependancies

Comment: Did you fix this problem or do you need some more help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the VB6 Package & Deployment wizard to generate an installer that will embed all the requirements and dependencies that your application needs to run.

That wizard is part of the VB6 development environment. Check the VB Start menu folder to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Install the comdlg32 manually following the instructions on this site

http://devonenote.com/2010/02/register-comdlg32-ocx-on-x64-win7/

comdlg32 was not included in Vista and up.

**NOTE** Notice the different location to drop the file if it is a 64bit OS. And it may require you to run regsvr32.exe as administrator.  Just follow the instructions on the link above.  Should work.